# Convert IVectorView to std::span

Tags: c++-winrt, cppwinrt

`winrt::hstring` is convertible to `std::basic_string_view` which comes in handy quite often. However, I am unable to do the same for IVectorView.

Looking at the interface of `IVector`, I imagine you would have to convert it back to the underlying implementation type so I tried

```cpp
using impl_type = winrt::impl::vector_impl<float, std::vector<float>, winrt::impl::single_threaded_collection_base>;
winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView vector_view = GetIVectorView();
auto& impl = *winrt::get_self<impl_type>(vector_view);
auto& container = impl.get_container();
```

which compiles but `container.size()` is `0` which is incorrect.

---

**Edit:**

`vector_view` was the result of the `TensorFloat.GetAsVectorView` Method. So I can solve my problem by using the `TensorFloat.CreateReference` Method to get a `IMemoryBufferReference` instead of a `IVectorView`.

However, I'd still like to know whether `IVectorView` can be converted to a std::span, if not why is this not allowed.

Comment: What's `GetIVectorView()`, and what type does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IVector` and `IVectorView` interfaces are specifically designed not to expose the underlying contiguous memory, probably to support cases where there is no underlying contiguous memory or the implementation language doesn't expose it as such (javascript??).

You probably could get back the implementation type in when you know cppwinrt provides the implementation, however I'm my case there is no possible way of knowing the implemention type. In any case, it's inadvisable to do this.

In my case it would have been better if `TensorFloat.GetAsVectorView` did not exist so I could find `TensorFloat.CreateReference`.

Also it would be nice if cppwinrt made themselves range-v3 compatible. But until the most advisable thing to do is just copy to a std::vector.